# Xcode does not allow me to specify file name when adding in SPM

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a stand alone SPM (local) in my project. When ever I add any new files to this package Xcode does not show the prompt to specify the name. Usually when adding files in a project it requests the location which allows to specify a name. But when adding in a SPM it straight away creates a file with `File.swift` always.

I don't mind renaming but its just that the header is also having a generic `File.swift`

```
//
//  File.swift
//  
//
//  Created by McDuck, Scrooge on 02/06/89.
//
```

Any work arounds ?

I have tried on Xcode 13.4 as well

Comment: Do you want to customize the file header for new files?

Comment: No I don't want any customisations just the regular flow where it allows us to specify a file name. If you create a new file in a iOS project before creating the file Xcode presents the finder dialog where you get a chance to give your desired file name. But for some reason when working on local SPM (standalone) it just drops in a generic `File.swift` without presenting the finder, which is just annoying to rename all the time. Since its not happening in the latest Xcode 13.4 as well any workarounds ?

Answer (score 4):

@user5381191 I had the same problem. I did some searching and found [this answer](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-package-manager-project-dont-generate-filename-and-boilerplates/49625/3).

The file you want to edit is located in:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Source/Package Swift File.xctemplate`. Edit the `TemplateInfo.plist`.

<strike>As a test I just copied the `TemplateInfo.plist` file from the `Multiplatform/Source/Swift File.xctemplate` and it worked.</strike> EDIT: For some reason it worked, and then stopped working?

Copy the suggested plist text from the link above into your template file and it works!

Once I did that, I get a new file type "Package Swift File" in the New File dialog.

[image: New File dialog]

Instead of the standard file dialog, it gives a dialog for entering the file name. Better than before!

[image]

Make sure to save your old template file before making your changes, just in case you need to revert.

It doesn't insert the package name in the header. That might be a nice thing to try and get working, but I'm happy with this for now.

Comment: For me it only worked after editing the file from `Multiplatform/Source/Swift File.xctemplate`